# WSO2 API Manager - How to proxy a SOAP Service that has a basic Auth

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using wso2 api manager. I cannot publish an existing SOAP service that has a basic auth (in the back end). The publisher interface let you insert the wsdl location, but obviously it requires a basic auth (in fact i have a 401 error in the log).

I tried to put username and password in the url like https://username:pwd@server...  but it does not work.

Thank you

Comment: On the implement tab, did you select "See more options" at the bottom of the Endpoint section?  It allows you to select Secured or Unsecured and then you can indicate Basic Auth.  We use this sucessfully to authenticate to our SOAP Services that require Basic Auth.

Comment: But i cannot go on the implement tab. I'm stopped in the WSDL definition because it is protected by basic auth.